# POST and GET error after migrating Laravel project to new instance. What's the cause?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, redhat

I moved my Laravel project an AWS instance. Everything appeared to work fine. When I go to login I get the error `"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."` which appears to occur on the `login(Request $request){}` function found here
`./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` I've tried the project on both Ubuntu and Redhat instances and get same error. I'm trying to find other ways of troubleshooting this error. Any advice would be appreciated.

form

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('2faconfirm') }}">
```

routes

```
Route::post('2faverify', [ 'as' => '2faverify', 'uses' => 'MFAController@verify']);
Route::post('2faconfirm', [ 'as' => '2faconfirm', 'uses' => 'MFAVerifyController@confirm']);

The process I took to migrate
- Dump mysql db for lavarel
- import laravel to new instances
- install php/mysql/composer/npm
- copy over files
- edit .env file to new db
```

@aynber brought up a good point. I am using redirect in code.

```
    public function 2faverify(Request $request)
    {
        $response = $this->2faSendCode($request->get('email'), $request->get('password'));

        $client   = app()->make(CognitoClient::class);

        if($client->getUserStatus($request->get('email')) == 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD'){
            return view('auth.passwords.force-password-reset', ['session'=>$response['Session']]);
        }
        if(gettype($response) != 'string'){
            return view('2faverify',['session' => $response['Session']]);
        }else{
            return redirect('login')->withErrors([$response]);
        }
    }





    public function 2faconfirm(Request $request){

        $email      = $request->get('email');
        $password   = $request->get('password');
        $session    = $request->get('session');
        $2faCode    = $request->get('2facode');
        $client     = app()->make(CognitoClient::class);

        if($client->confirm2fa($email, $password,$session, $2faCode)){
            $this->login($request);
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }else{
            return redirect('login')->withErrors(['Code expired!']);
        }

    }
```

but i don't see how this could be the issue since if it errors on `return redirect(` that means I've at least successfully logged in. But I'm not logged in after this error.

`php artisan optimize`
errors below

```
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at /var/www/html/wave-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919|
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      /var/www/html/wave-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      /var/www/html/wave-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I corrected this error by removing the following from routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I can run optimize without errors

```
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!
Routes cached successfully!
Files cached successfully!
```

but this did not fix the POST error on login.

Comment: Do you have any redirects? A redirect will change the method from POST to GET. You can watch the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what is happening with the request.

Comment: Would the redirect be in code or in apache2?

Comment: It could be in the code, it could be in apache2, it could be in your .htaccess file.

Comment: The redirect would happen before it gets to the 2faconfirm function.

Comment: I posted that portion of the code as well. I don't do any redirects unless there was an error. In apache2 i only have mod_rewrite enabled. The .htaccess file only reflects the mod_rewrite and no other params.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan optimize`  in your server to set your cache,routes etc etc?

Comment: I have not. Looks like it errors. I've posted the error.

Answer (score 0):

To Anyone having this issue in the future. This error is incredibly misleading, as you can tell. It turns out that the error was due to laravel being unable to connect to or find an existing user that is attempting the login. I found the issue by running the following inside my login code.

```
 use App\User; //be sure to include in top of page else a new error will appear

        $user = User::where('email', '=', $request->get('email'))->first();
        if ($user === null) {
           echo "user does not exist";
        } else{
           echo "exists";
        }
        exit();
```

I continued to get user does not exist. I corrected the db issues but still errored that user does not exist. Finally, I ran the following and it fixed the issue.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

This was two part error. It couldn't find user in the db and once i fixed db connection it couldn't connect because it was using old config in cache. Clearing cache fixed it.